# Insert Excel charts using Microsoft Graph in a PowerPoint Add-in sample

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, office-js

I am trying to get this sample ([Insert Excel charts using Microsoft Graph in a PowerPoint Add-in](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PowerPoint-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-ASPNET-InsertChart/blob/master/README.md)) working in PowerPoint. One of the requirement is that a specific version of PowerPoint "PowerPoint for Windows Desktop, version 16.0.6769.2001 or higher" is needed. I have Office 365 subscription (work related) and my PowerPoint version is "16.0.6001.1068". I have already checked in PowerPoint for any available update but it comes back saying my version is up to date.

The question is - how else can i get the "16.0.6769.2001" version? Any help would be appreciated.

BTW: i did go through all the other settings and instruction to setup the the sample. When i load PowerPoint and insert a chart, the add in never loads.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using O365 from your company, the admin in your organization may choose to delay Office updates. Therefore, you may not able to get the latest Office. But you can always sign up an Office developer account for free and get the latest bits. You can sign up for free here[Office 365 Developer Subscription](https://portal.office.com/Signup/Signup.aspx?OfferId=6881A1CB-F4EB-4db3-9F18-388898DAF510&DL=DEVELOPERPACK&ali=1#0). This includes the resources you need to start building apps.

Thanks,
Sky,
Office Extensibility Team